# Have to execute .Replace twice to replace text in pipe-delimited file using PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I have a PowerShell script that looks in a folder for one or more pipe-delimited HL7 files, combines them into a single file, strips out some unnecessary lines, then delivers the file to an inventory control application. The last thing the script needs to do is replace any occurrences of |""| with || using the below code (where $outputFilePath holds the pathname to the file.)

```
if (Test-Path $outputFilePath) {
    # Read the content of the file
    $replacefile = (Get-Content $outputFilePath).Replace('|""|', '||') 
    $replacefile | Set-Content -Path $outputFilePath
```

I can see the code execute by stepping through it with the debugger, but the file will still contain all instances of |""|. BUT, if I duplicate the code and run it a second time (like below), the file will then contain only || for any empty fields.

```
# first pass appears to do nothing
if (Test-Path $outputFilePath) {
    # Read the content of the file
    $replacefile = (Get-Content $outputFilePath).Replace('|""|', '||') 
    $replacefile | Set-Content -Path $outputFilePath
} 

# do it again and it works
if (Test-Path $outputFilePath) {
    # Read the content of the file
    $replacefile = (Get-Content $outputFilePath).Replace('|""|', '||') 
    $replacefile | Set-Content -Path $outputFilePath
}
```

The files are never more than 2K lines and the repeat doesn't significantly increase processing time, so there's no problem just running it as is. But I'd really like to know what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Comment: How about `Get-Content -Path $outputFilePath -Raw`?

Comment: @lit, that's a sensible performance optimization, but doesn't explain jere413's symptom - and  I have no explanation for the latter.

Comment: "... but the file will still contain all instances of `|""|`." - how are you determining this? I'm entirely unable to reproduce the behavior described - reading the file back with `Get-Content` after doing the `Replace()` operation (just once) works as expected

Comment: `Get-Content` reads the file into memory but the file is not always released after. 
Try piping the output of `Get-Content` to `Out-String` before performing the replace. `(Get-Content $outputFilePath | Out-String).Replace('|""|', '||') `

Comment: @MartinIszac, enclosing a `Get-Content` call in `(...)` is sufficient for the file to be closed agin by the time the results are returned (collected in memory, in full).